# How can I find the output file of a python os script if I don't know the name of it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operating-system

I am writing a loop to generate files in python using the os package. My issue is every time I generate the file, I need to check if the file contents satisfy requirements and discard it if it doesn't. I don't know the name of the file as well since its composed of a randomly generated name so I need another way to reference it in my code. Since I have a large data set I don't want to do this manually.

My question is then how can I reference the file that was just outputted as a result of an os command?

here is my code if that helps

```
# each row is for one patient
for row in range(2):
    #for each id, find descriptors
    local_id=df.loc[row,'# localid']
    age=str(df.loc[row,'Age'])
    if df.loc[row,'gender']=='Female':
        gender='F'
    else: gender='M'
    indication=df.loc[row,'indication']
    race=df.loc[row,'race']

    #run loop to run until matching generated patient has matching race and indication
    check=True
    while check:
        if indication=='Breast carcinoma':
            os.system('run_synthea -p 1 -a '+age+' -g '+gender+' -m breast_cancer')
        elif indication=='Hyperlipidemia':
            os.system('run_synthea -p 1 -a '+age+' -g '+gender+' -m veteran_hyperlipidemia')
        elif indication=='Colorectal Cancer / Polyps':
            os.system('run_synthea -p 1 -a '+age+' -g '+gender+' -m colorectal_cancer')
        else: #runs for , not selected, healthy, ovarian cancer, and heart diseases
            os.system('run_synthea -p 1 -a '+age+' -g '+gender)

        # INSET CODE , find output file 
        output_file=''
        has_indication=check_indication(output_file, indication)
        has_race=json.load(output_file)['entry'][0]['resource']['extension'][0]['extension'][1]['valueString']
        if has_indication and has_race==race:
            deID=output_file['entry'][0]['resource']['id']
            thewriter.writerow([local_id,deID])
            check=False
```

Comment: If the file is written into current working directory, create a new directory, use it as working directory and afterwards search for the file.

Comment: when `run_synthea` is run is its output the name of the file its created with the data?

Comment: You need to provide more details about `run_synthea`. What is its purpose and how does it create that file (according to what rules)? What is its output? Do you have control over that application?

Comment: Do you know the output directory?

Comment: I need to change `run_synthea` to `java -jar synthea-with-dependencies.jar`, I haven't been able to get this to work yet so I'm still working on that part. But the output is a synthetic electronic health record in json format where the name of the file consists of a randomly generated name and ID, and I know the output directory. So then for every loop, should I try referencing the most recent file created then ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the directory where the new files will be, you can take a snapshot of the directory before and after. This is fragile because it assumes that nothing else fiddles with the directory while the command is running.

```
import os

target_dir = "." # assume current working directory

before_list = set(os.listdir(target_dir))
os.system(...)
new_files = set(os.listdir(target_dir)) - before_list
```

Better to create a directory specifically for the task

```
import tempfile
import subprocess as subp
import os

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix="synthea_", dir=".") as prog_dir:
    result = qsubp.run(
        'run_synthea -p 1 -a '+age+' -g '+gender+' -m breast_cancer',
        shell=True, cwd=prog_dir)
    out_files = [fn for fn in os.listdir(prog_dir)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(prog_dir, fn))]
    # move files out of temp dir before it is deleted
    for fn in out_files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(prog_dir, fn), fn))
```

Now `out_files` holds a list of the files created and moved to the current directory.